# How can I print a specific message on close of browser tab?

Tags: javascript, java, php

I would like to print a message on the close of the browser tab. Something like this:

> Please don't close this tab.....an important file is running on the same tab............closing this may lose the data

How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`window.onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Example)

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
    return "Do you want to close?";
}
```